# I keep getting an infinite loop in c++

Tags: case

can someone please let me know why this infinite loop is happening when I run this code?

https://onlinegdb.com/NAsJPGoN7

Comment: If your "gdb" environment has a debugger, you could look at the loop occurring and maybe figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you need to convert `int newUserInput;` to `char newUserInput;`

Also please try to avoid this type of code when you can

```
while (1) {
...
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  What could i do insted of that type of code